# Polyline corners do not join properly

Tags: android

Im using this below library but Polyline corners do not join properly android. Can any one give the solution please?

```
implementation 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.1.1'
```

[image]

Java Code Here,

```
   GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
            .from(startlatlng)
            .and(wayLatLng)
            .to(destlatlng)
            .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
            .execute(this);
```

Comment: Please add your code that does the current line drawing to your question

Comment: @petey. I have posted my code here.